# Iterate trough json dict until entry is found or pass error with python

Tags: python, json

I have a python dict with nested entries, like this:

```
[{
        "id": "lorem",
        "name": "lorem",
        "info": "lorem",
        "system": 
                    {
                    "0": {"0": "initial question", "1": "lorem", "2": "lorem"},
                    "A": {"n":"lorem", "n":"lorem"}
                    },
        "result": {"n":"lorem", "n":"lorem"}
}]
```

Via an input from the console I want to find the id of my dict and continue from there

my code so far:

```
query = input("Type in the id: ", )
while True:
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if query in data[i]["id"]:
            print(" ")
            print("You have selected:", data[i]["name"])
            break
        if query:
            print("Classification not listed! Try again")
            print(" ")
            query = input("Type in the classification: ", )
            continue
        
#continue here with the code
```

I know that my problem is the for loop and that I should let my code try to iterate through my json dict until an id is found, and that it should only print the "Classification not listed!" statement if my query input did not match with any id in my data.

However, I cant figure out the correct way.

Comment: why the while true ?

Comment: Because if have multiple loops, where I need to jump to and from

Answer (score 2):

You need to restructure the loop so that the input happens inside the `while`, not the `for`.  Use an `else` on the `for` to catch the case where the `for` is being exhausted with no `break`:

```
while True:
    query = input("Type in the id: " )
    for i in data:
        if query in i["id"]:
            print("\nYou have selected:", i["name"])
            break  # to the bottom of the while loop
    else:
        # we just finished the entire "for" without a break
        print("Classification not listed! Try again\n")
        continue  # back to the top of the while loop
    break  # we just broke the "for", now break the "while"

# continue here with the code
```

A less complicated way of accomplishing the same objective might be to put the matching items in a list:

```
while True:
    query = input("Type in the id: " )
    selected = [i for i in data if query in i["id"]]
    if selected:
        print("\nYou have selected:", *(i['name'] for i in selected))
        break
    else:
        print("Classification not listed! Try again\n")

# continue here with the code
```

Note that the version of the code with the list makes it easier to see that you might have more than one match -- you can of course just take `selected[0]` if you want to arbitrarily take the first match and discard the others, but having all the matches in a list gives you other options as well.